# what’s the book called, it’s about a girl and boy being able to telepathically communicate without knowing each other? they don’t know each other

Tags: story-identification, powers, telepathy

Main girl doesn’t know she’s a witch.

Both characters (boy and a girl) don’t know each other prior to being able to telepathically communicate with each other.

I think the cover had some sort of gate? I’ve tried searching in many websites have not found it yet

Comment: We could use a lot more details. Length of story, when you read it, format. See here for more prompts. https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337

Answer (score 4):

Could possibly be "A Message From Charity", better known as a *Twilight Zone* episode but apparently based on [a short story by William M. Lee](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?53876).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Message_from_Charity):

> Two teenagers – Peter Wood, an academically overachieving loner from 1985, and Charity Payne, a Puritan from 1700 Colonial Massachusetts, come in telepathic contact with each other when they have the same fever.

I thought of this specifically because you mentioned being a witch: Charity is accused of witchcraft when she mentions some of the things she has learned from Peter.

Comment: If so, a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/231940/young-adult-book-about-telepathy-across-time?noredirect=1&lq=1, which was accepted by comment.